# How to activate/switch which XFCE panel is used on a monitor?

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor

I have configured a panel 1 used on monitor 1 (laptop), and panel 2 for a second monitor (hdmi). When I disconnect the second monitor, panel 2 is used on my laptop. I need it to be panel 1 (which has the Notifications Area), but I can't see how to switch to panel 1.

Comment: Could  [the steps outlined in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62681/how-do-i-setup-dual-monitors-in-xfce/62682) help with your issue?

Comment: If your panels are not locked into position, you could integrate the following command into a script to run to adjust the panel position when you have the monitor connected or when it is only the laptop. `xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/position -t string -s 'p=12;x=1600;y=900'` Of course you would need to adjust the position values and whether it is `panel-1` or `panel-2`. Run Settings Editor to see your panel positioning for both scenarios.